# Vertical alignment in cell of longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

I am using a `longtable` where I'd like to align the content of a specific cell vertically to the top.

[image]

So far, I only found examples for `tabularx` which seem to made use of `\cmidrule`. But this does not seem to work with `longtable`.

I am sure there's a way to achieve this, therefore I am thankful for your inputs!

*Latex Code*

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Präambel                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Packages        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Dokument                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\tablestyle[sansbold]
\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.75\textwidth}}}
\theadstart
    \thead Bezeichner &
    \thead UC02: MultiSelectionField (Desktop) \\ 
\tbody
Beschreibung & Das bestehende SelectionField soll so erweitert werden, dass im Dropdown, abhängig von der Eingabe, entsprechende Vorschläge zur Auswahl angezeigt werden und mehrere Auswahlen möglich sind und wieder entfernt werden können. \\
 Akteure & Anwendungsbenutzer \\ 
 Vorbedingungen & Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} ist noch leer. \\
 Nachbedingung & Eine Auswahl von 1-n Elementen wurde durch den Anwendungsbenutzer getätigt. Die Auswahl ist im \texttt{MultiSelectionField} sichtbar. Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} wird als valid angezeigt. \\
 Hauptszenario &
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer fokussiert das \texttt{MultiSelectionField}.
            \item Das Dropdown erscheint, mit allen Auswahlsmöglichkeiten.
            \item Der {Anwendungsbenutzer} tippt eine Eingabe ins Textfeld des SelectionFields.
            \item Das Dropdown filtert die Auswahlsmöglichkeiten anhand der Eingabe im Textfeld des \texttt{MultiSelectionField}.
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer wählt ein Element per Mausklick im Dropdown an.
            \item Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} leert alle Texteingaben und das selektierte Element wird anschliessend darin angezeigt.
            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer wiederholt Schritt 2-5 solange bis die gewünschte Auswahl getroffen wurde.
            \item Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} zeigt alle ausgewählten Elemente an.
        \end{enumerate}
     \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't copy some arbitrary code into your question. Make a small complete example that actually demonstrates your problem (and runs without error). And clean up your preamble. You are loading various package twice. And using both fontenc/lmodern and fontspec doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, wrong document. I updated the code with a minimal example.

Comment: As I wrote: clean up and shorten your example. There are lots of unneeded packages to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Cleaned up further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the space around the enumerate with the options: `topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Präambel                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Packages        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Dokument                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\tablestyle[sansbold]
\begin{longtable}{*{2}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.75\textwidth}}}
    \theadstart
    \thead Bezeichner &
    \thead UC02: MultiSelectionField (Desktop)                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\
    \tbody
    Beschreibung      & Das bestehende SelectionField soll so erweitert werden, dass im Dropdown, abhängig von der Eingabe, entsprechende Vorschläge zur Auswahl angezeigt werden und mehrere Auswahlen möglich sind und wieder entfernt werden können. \\
    Akteure           & Anwendungsbenutzer                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\
    Vorbedingungen    & Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} ist noch leer.                                                                                                                                                                                 \\
    Nachbedingung     & Eine Auswahl von 1-n Elementen wurde durch den Anwendungsbenutzer getätigt. Die Auswahl ist im \texttt{MultiSelectionField} sichtbar. Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} wird als valid angezeigt.                                \\
    Hauptszenario     & \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, leftmargin=*]
                            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer fokussiert das \texttt{MultiSelectionField}.
                            \item Das Dropdown erscheint, mit allen Auswahlsmöglichkeiten.
                            \item Der {Anwendungsbenutzer} tippt eine Eingabe ins Textfeld des SelectionFields.
                            \item Das Dropdown filtert die Auswahlsmöglichkeiten anhand der Eingabe im Textfeld des \texttt{MultiSelectionField}.
                            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer wählt ein Element per Mausklick im Dropdown an.
                            \item Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} leert alle Texteingaben und das selektierte Element wird anschliessend darin angezeigt.
                            \item Der Anwendungsbenutzer wiederholt Schritt 2-5 solange bis die gewünschte Auswahl getroffen wurde.
                            \item Das \texttt{MultiSelectionField} zeigt alle ausgewählten Elemente an.
                        \end{enumerate} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this looks nice! Btw, did you format the table code automatically?

Comment: Uhm, I think my editor (nvim + [texlab](https://github.com/latex-lsp/texlab)) did it

Comment: Thx, unfortunately Overleaf seems not to have this option.